# need help with geometric series

Tags: geometric-series

could any one give me hint how to solve $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{(-2)^n}  $$

using the geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$ 3 \sum_{n \geq 1} \left( \frac{-1}{2} \right)^n = 3 \sum_{n \geq 0} \left( \frac{-1}{2} \right)^n -  3 = 3 \cdot \frac{ 1 }{1 + \frac{1}{2}} -3 = 3 \cdot \frac{2}{3} - 3 = -1$$

Comment: @ ILoveMath should it be -1?

Comment: you are right, just fixed it

Comment: The sum is $S = 3\cdot \frac{a}{1-r} = 3\cdot \frac{-\frac 12}{1 - (-\frac 12)} = -3\cdot \frac 13 = -1$ Oh, you just fixed it, never mind.

Comment: @ ILoveMath I just figured how to use the geometric series to find the limit as n approaches infinity, although your answer did not strictly used the geometric series, it did help me. thanks.